# void* array convert element to another type

Tags: c++, x86-64, data-conversion, void-pointers

I have something like this:

```
void* a[] = {(void*)"Hello",(void*)1};
cout << (char*)a[0] << endl;
cout << (int)(int64_t)((int*)a[1]) << endl;
```

How I can simplify line
**(int)(int64_t)((int*)a[1])**

Is it possible to change the void * into an int easier?

Comment: What are you expecting `(int)(int64_t)((int*)a[1])` to do?

Comment: Sounds like you could use a `std::vector` of `std::variant` or `std::any` instead of all this pointer cast hell.

Comment: Well, how do you retrieve the thing a pointer points to? You dereference the pointer, you don't normally cast pointers to non-pointer types.

Comment: `(void*)1` I'm not sure what you intended to do with this but this seems very odd to me.

Comment: Are you trying to implement `printf`-style `va_arg` array or something?

Comment: @Borgleader pre-c++11, would be the only way to pass integer argument to thread function, for example.

Comment: I want create array contains different types. In my example, I wanted make array with string and int.

Comment: `I want create array contains different types` You can't.

Answer (score 2):

```
void* a[] = {static_cast<void*>(const_cast<char*>("Hello")),reinterpret_cast<void*>(static_cast<omyptr_t>(1))};
std::cout << static_cast<char*>(a[0]) << std::endl;
std::cout << static_cast<int>(reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(a[1])) << std::endl;
```

I think that is all defined behaviour.

Always cast back to the exact same when casting from `void*`.  Avoid using raw C casts, as it can be static, const or reinterpret casts, and doing the wrong one can really break things.

Consider using `std::any` or `boost::any` instead of raw void pointers; or variants if you know a fixed set of types to store.

Comment: Well, this answer, although correct, hardly answers the punchline in the question, which is "How I can simplify line (int)(int64_t)((int*)a[1])".

Comment: @serg I did rewrite the line.  It is longer, but arguably simpler it requires far less of the standard to understand what it does, and is correct.

Comment: "*How I can simplify line `(int)(int64_t)((int*)a[1])`*" well, it doesn't get much simpler than `(int)a[1]` for 32bit and `(int64_t)a[1]` for 64bit, or safer `(intptr_t)a[1]` for both, though `reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(a[1])` would be better. There is no need to `static_cast` the `intptr_t` to `int` when calling `operator<<` since it has overloads for 32bit and 64bit integers

Comment: @remy what if `intptr_t` is a distinct type that isn't `int` or `lomg`?  Is there a guarantee that there is a `<<` overload for ostream?  There might be, but the OP wanted an int, and `1` is an int.

Answer (score 0):

Does it *have* to be an array of `void*`?  **It looks like you should just use a union.**

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

union pointer_or_integer_t {
    void *vp;
    uintptr_t u;
    intptr_t i;
};

static_assert(sizeof(void *) == sizeof(pointer_or_integer_t),
              "intptr_t or uintptr_t are larger than the size as a pointer");

int main() {
    pointer_or_integer_t a[] = {(void*)"Hello", {.i = 1}};

    std::cout << (const char*)a[0].vp << '\n';
    std::cout << a[1].i << '\n';
}
```

(Don't use `std::endl` unless you actually want to force a flush.)

This compiles to code that does what we want, with no extra overhead [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Ccstdint%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Aunion+pointer_or_integer_t+%7B%0A++++void+*vp%3B%0A++++uintptr_t+u%3B%0A++++intptr_t+i%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astatic_assert(sizeof(void+*)+%3D%3D+sizeof(pointer_or_integer_t),%0A++++++++++++++%22intptr_t+or+uintptr_t+are+larger+than+the+size+as+a+pointer%22)%3B%0A%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++pointer_or_integer_t+a%5B%5D+%3D+%7B(void*)%22Hello%22,+%7B.i+%3D+1%7D%7D%3B%0A%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+(const+char*)a%5B0%5D.vp+%3C%3C+!'%5Cn!'%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+a%5B1%5D.i+%3C%3C+!'%5Cn!'%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:42.84957627118644,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g82,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-Wall+-std%3Dc%2B%2B11+-pedantic',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:32.86455983036697,l:'4',m:58.65865865865866,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+8.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:41.34134134134134,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:57.15042372881356,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).

Note that a `{.i = 1}` designated-initializer in C++ is currently a GNU extension, but will be part of C++20.  g++8.2 `-pedantic` warns:

```
<source>:15:50: warning: C++ designated initializers only available with -std=c++2a or -std=gnu++2a [-Wpedantic]

     pointer_or_integer_t a[] = {(void*)"Hello", {.i = 1}};
                                              ^
```

---

You could also maybe use a union of `void []` and `uintptr_t[]`, but that only works easily if the size is known.  Making each array element its own union works better.

I think it's still UB to type-pun the array-of-union to array-of-`void*` with a cast (instead of `memcpy`), even if you use asserts to check that it has the same layout.

But if you have an interface that only lets you pass a `void **`, you can cast that back to `pointer_or_integer_t **` in the receiving function.  There's no UB at all if no code ever actually indexes the `void **`.

There's usually no problem in practice if something does index into the object as a `void **`, because your union has the same object-representation as an array of `void*`.